# Manual Validation to create/review/complete PR in AzureDevOps

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have the following YAML task to create a PR via Azure DevOps automatically:

```
  - task: AzurePowerShell@4
    displayName: 'Create a PR from develop to main on public repository'
    inputs:
      azurePowerShellVersion: latestVersion
      azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.serviceConnection }}
      scriptType: inlineScript
      inline: |       
        $user = ""
        $branchTarget = "refs/heads/main"
        $branchSource = "refs/heads/develop"
        $branchTargetPath = $branchTarget -replace "refs/heads/", ""
        $teamProject = "Project"
        $repoName = "Repo"
        $organization = "Org"
        $base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$PersonalAccessToken)))       
        $uriCreatePR = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$teamProject/_apis/git/repositories/$repoName/pullrequests?api-version=5.1"
        $bodyCreatePR = "{sourceRefName:'$branchSource',targetRefName:'$branchTarget',title:'PR'}"
        $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uriCreatePR -Method Post -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Body $bodyCreatePR
```

I need to add a ManualValidation task after the above task

```
    - task: ManualValidation@0
      timeoutInMinutes: 1440 # task times out in 1 day
      inputs:
        notifyUsers: |
          ${{ parameters.email }}
        instructions: |
          1) Navigate here: // url of the PR created
          2) Review/Approve
        onTimeout: 'reject'
```

How do I pass the url of the PR created in the 1st task to the manual validation task?